# NHibernate join subquery

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have 3 simple tables (entities): `Page (id)`, `Control (id, page_id)` and `Setting (id, control_id)`.
So the structure is `Page->Control->Setting`.

I have query:

```
SELECT
p.*
,c.*
,s.*
FROM #page p
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM #control WHERE id = @controlid) c ON p.id = c.page_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM #settings WHERE id = @settingid) s ON s.id = c.page_id
WHERE
p.id = @pageid
```

How to build `NHibernate` construction to generate the same query?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @EricHerlitz I dont even know how to do someting like: .JoinQueryOver(subQuery).

Comment: In order to succeed you must have constructed objects and mappings that support the data model, did you do that and in that case please post the code.

Comment: @EricHerlitz ofcourse all stuff is done, mappings, etc. I'm asking about how to build the query

Comment: You can't join to arbitrary derived tables with QueryOver. You'll have to use HQL or SQL.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker it's imposible to do that by HQL (no such construction in HQL). I tried SQL, but mappings not working then. So, seems like there are no ability to make subquery in join, because of hibernate object model.

Comment: Fyi: I think you have an error in your sql query. I wouldn't think  setting id would ever equal page id. Also, what is the point of the sub queries? Why not join to the tables directly?

Answer (score 0):

If your datamodel is correct you would only have to do something like this

```
session.QueryOver<Page>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Control)
    .Eager.List<Page>();
```

Depending on a lot of thins you may have to implement `ThenFetch`.